# Compose ModalBottomSheet sheetContent is taking up space in UI even when not shown

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

When I use the ModalBottomSheetLayout, it seems to cause the UI to take up space for the bottomSheet content, even when the bottomSheet isn't being displayed.

```kotlin
val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState, 
        sheetContent = {
            SomeBottomSheetContent() //seems to be taking up space in the UI even when bottomSheet isn't visible
        }
    ) {
            MyRow(
                ... // uses some dynamic data known only at runtime
            )
      }
}
```

This is what is desired:

[image]

but instead, I get this:

[image]

*** Update ***

I think maybe this is happening because the ModalBottomSheetLayout was designed to be used at the page level, and so the sheetContent would need to be defined at compile time. If that's the case, how do I populate the sheetContent using dynamic data obtained at runtime?

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to have a dynamic bottom sheet content? something like everytime you open it or from some action the bottom sheet will have a different content? and based on your screenshot, you seem like to have a column/LazyColumn that keeps adding up?

Comment: @z.g.y yes! I need a bottomsheet with dynamic content. Yes it is a lazyColumn with rows